# How to query a text with '&' in salesforce rest API?

Tags: python, rest, postman, salesforce, salesforce-rest-api

I want to query a condition that include & in salesforce using rest API.

Eg:

> {{instance_url}}/services/data/v55.0/queryAll?q=SELECT+FIELDS(STANDARD)+FROM+Case+WHERE+Status+IN+('Started','**In
> Progress &  Review**','Completed')

It splitting the query by &. So I changed & to `%26` (url encoded of &), now the Salesforce not identified its status.

Comment: Can you please add in your question the URL with %26 in it? Also, did you try to escape the spaces in “progress & review”?

Comment: @TomHerman Thanks for your comment. %26 working fine now. It was my typo, there was a extra whitespace after %26 in my request. So I removed the that white space and its working fine.